# Coloring 2 Ovals with Graphics2D

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

I want to Color 2 Ovals in Java with Graphics2D. Oval1(`point`) Green and Oval2(`point2`) Blue. The Problem is that Oval2 becomes green and Oval1 black. Does somebody knows what the problem is?

[image]
left(oval1) right(oval2)

Here is the SSCCE:

**`GameView.java`**

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import stackoverflow.GameView;

public class GameView extends JFrame{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Game game = new Game();

    public GameView(){
        JFrame gameFrame = new JFrame("Game");
        gameFrame.setSize(500, 300);
        gameFrame.setVisible(true);
        gameFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gameFrame.add(game);        
        game.runGame();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        new GameView();     
    }
}
```

**`Game.java`**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import stackoverflow.Point;

public class Game extends JPanel{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Point point = new Point(Color.GREEN);
    private Point point2 = new Point(Color.BLUE);

    public void runGame(){
        repaint();
        point2.setX(300);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        point.paint(g);
        point2.paint(g);
    }   
}
```

**`Point.java`**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;

public class Point {

    private int x = 100;
    private int y = 100;
    private int width = 10;
    private int height = 10;

    private Color color;

    public Point(Color color){
        this.color = color;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;    
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.fillOval(x, y, width, height);
        g2d.setColor(this.color);
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the order of these calls...

```
g2d.fillOval(x, y, width, height);
g2d.setColor(this.color);
```

And you should be painting in `JPanel.paintComponent` instead.

Comment: Right-o @AndrewThompson And I really must learn that source code formatting stuff.

Comment: *"source code formatting stuff"*  Select the code sample and click the `{}` button above the message posting/editing form.  :)

Comment: Everything is easy when you know it. Thanks. ☺